# Opencart products page with special price

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I want to have example.com/special and there list products with special price, what is the best way to do that ?

Requirements: 1.

- have url /specials/
- use category.tpl template

My idea: create new page in information, in controller send parms to catalog/category to fetch specials products, maybe exist more clear way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Special page is available by default in OpenCart. When You will set “old price – new price” for product. So, It product will automatically added in special page.

You can see in default OpenCart special page demo. [Click Here](http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=product/special)

**For example** a product may have cost $200, but using the specials option in OpenCart you can set the price to $150. That way customers see the “old price – new price” difference.

Here’s how to set up a **specials** in OpenCart

1. From your OpenCart admin interface, hover over the Catalog tab and 
   click Products.
2. This is the list of products you have on your website. Find the
   product you want to discount and click Edit.
3. Click on the Special tab.
4. Click Add Special in order to fill in the information for your
   special price. Again, you have a number of options almost identical
       to the discount page: